# Iterate over unique combination of groups in a data frame

Tags: r, iteration, unique, dataframe, combinations

I have 3 different groups summarised in a data frame. The data frame looks like:

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"), 

                v2 = c(1:9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

What I want is to compare the values of A against values of B. Also values of A against values of B and as a last comparison the values of B against the values of C

I constructed 2 for loops to iterate over v1 to extract the groups to compare. However, the for-loops give me all possible combinations like:

A vs. A

A vs. B

A vs. C

B vs. A

B vs. B

B vs. C

C vs. A and so on...

Here are my for-loops:

```
for(i in unique(d$v1)) {

    for(j in unique(d$v1)) {

        cat("i = ", i, "j = ", j, "\n")

        group1 <- d[which(d$v1 == i), ]

            group2 <- d[which(d$v1 == j), ]

        print(group1)
        print(group2)

        cat("---------------------\n\n")

    }
}
```

How can I manage to only iterate over data frame `d` so that in the first iteration group1 contains the values of A and group2 contains the values of B. In the second iteration group1 contains the values of A and group2 the values of C. And as a last comparisons group1 contains values of B and group2 contains values of C.

I am somehow totally stuck with that problem and hoping to find an answer here.

Cheers!

Comment: What kind of comparisons do you want to perform ?

Comment: well, instead of having only v2 my original data frame has up to 10 columns. So basically group1 is a sub data frame of d with 11 columns(c1=v1 and c2:11 = additional information) for v1 == A. Accordingly, group2 is the same subset but with the values for v1 == B. I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work for you. With some more work, the output can be "tidied-up" a little bit too.

We'll use `combn` to find out the combinations, and `lapply` to subset our data based on the combinations:

```
temp = combn(unique(d$v1), 2)
temp
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "A"  "A"  "B" 
# [2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 
lapply(1:ncol(temp), function(x) cbind(d[d$v1 == temp[1, x], ],
                                       d[d$v1 == temp[2, x], ]))
# [[1]]
#   v1 v2 v1 v2
# 1  A  1  B  4
# 2  A  2  B  5
# 3  A  3  B  6
# 
# [[2]]
#   v1 v2 v1 v2
# 1  A  1  C  7
# 2  A  2  C  8
# 3  A  3  C  9
# 
# [[3]]
#   v1 v2 v1 v2
# 4  B  4  C  7
# 5  B  5  C  8
# 6  B  6  C  9
```

Comment: Of course, you may also prefer using `rbind` or `list` instead of `cbind` after the `function(x)...`.

Comment: Great way of doing it. thanks a lot. That is a way I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I personally like mrdwab answer for its elegance, but if you still want to do it your way with the loops I'd fix it with this (take into account this will mess up your code, it's better to keep it tidy :)

```
u <- unique(d$v1)
for (i in 1:length(u)) {
    if (i < length(u)) {
        for (j in u[(i+1):length(u)]) {
            group1 <- d[which(d$v1 == u[i]), ]
            group2 <- d[which(d$v1 == j), ]
            cat("i = ", u[i], "j = ", j, "\n")
            print(group1)
            print(group2)
            cat("---------------------\n\n")
        }
    }
}
```

And result in this:

```
i =  A j =  B 
  v1 v2
1  A  1
2  A  2
3  A  3
  v1 v2
4  B  4
5  B  5
6  B  6
---------------------

i =  A j =  C 
  v1 v2
1  A  1
2  A  2
3  A  3
  v1 v2
7  C  7
8  C  8
9  C  9
---------------------

i =  B j =  C 
  v1 v2
4  B  4
5  B  5
6  B  6
  v1 v2
7  C  7
8  C  8
9  C  9
---------------------
```

Comment: Well sorted :) However, as you said, I think mrdwab's solution is a better way of doing it :)